# Could not bind TCP port 443 LetsEncrypt

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Could not bind TCP port 443 because it is already in use by another process on this system (such as a web server). Please stop the program in question and then try again

My operating system is (include version): mac OS Sierra version 10.12

My web server is (include version): apache2-mod-php7.0_7.0.15

My hosting provider, if applicable, is: Linode (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS)

I can login to a root shell on my machine (yes or no, or I don't know): not sure

I'm using a control panel to manage my site (no, or provide the name and version of the control panel): I use terminal and filezilla

Question is how do stop the program??? If any more details are required, let me know!

Comment: LetsEncrypt has some issues with MAC/iPhone/... usage.

Comment: Thanks for responding. There has to be a way to stop or pause the web server though.

Answer (score 1):

i had also the same issue on Centos server this worked for me:

```
apachectl stop
```

in Ubuntu it should be something like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl stop apache2.service
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04 with the following error (`Problem binding to port 443: Could not bind to IPv4 or IPv6.`), this answer pointed me in the right direction by letting me know to stop apache, run the letsencrypt command, then start apache again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in terminal to list and search for process using a regex:-

```
ps gx | grep 'java'
```

The above example is to list all the 'Symantec' related processes. Replace 'Symantec' with your own phrase. Next use variations of 'kill' command. You can either use:-

```
kill pid
```

Replace 'pid' with actual process id. Or use,

```
killall
```

as suggested before. To reiterate another useful suggestion, use

```
man kill
```

to see the manual for 'kill' command and also scroll down and see related commands which is mentioned under, "SEE ALSO" section.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of killing apache, you could use the [letsencrypt certbot apache plugin](https://certbot.eff.org/#ubuntuxenial-apache). This way, Let's Encrypt is working with your setup instead of against it. Once you have certbot setup, it will automatically handle renewing the certificates for you as well.

To install certbot with the apache plugin, you will need to run the following commands on your server. In this case, you can use the [Linode Shell](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/using-the-linode-shell-lish/) to access your server.

Installation procedure (from the official docs):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache
```

Once that's installed, you can get the ssl certs automatically, and have them installed with one command:

```
certbot --apache
```

Comment: when i run: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot                                         it gives me the following: sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found

why is that? any idea?

Comment: @AliLakhany You need to run that command on your server. Since you're using Linode, you can run commands on your terminal from their website. See this guide: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/using-the-linode-shell-lish/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pre-hook and post-hook to always stop and start the webserver when renewing